# How to add a button programmatically in VBA next to some sheet cell data?

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have a function that generates data for say 100 rows (and 2 columns). For each row (in the 3rd column) I need to add a button which, when clicked, brings up a custom modal dialog box giving the user 4 options/buttons to choose from.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Checking: You want something like a List/ComboBox in the third column, but modal?

Comment: both belisarius and Remnant will work

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I think this is enough to get you on a nice path:

```
Sub a()
  Dim btn As Button
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
  Dim t As Range
  For i = 2 To 6 Step 2
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3))
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    With btn
      .OnAction = "btnS"
      .Caption = "Btn " & i
      .Name = "Btn" & i
    End With
  Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub btnS()
 MsgBox Application.Caller
End Sub
```

It creates the buttons and binds them to butnS(). In the btnS() sub, you should show your dialog, etc.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this works if you change 'target to 't' and 'tLeft' to 't.Left'

Comment: Great answer. After reading it, I sort of "discovered" this for myself by recording a macro.  But I can't seem to find any reference to Buttons, either in the Help, or the Object browser.  I must not be looking in the right place?

Comment: Thank you for the code! However, when I try to run it I get the error message "Expected end of statement" on the `Dim btn as button` line. I'm using Notepad++ to create my .vbs file, but it won't compile

Comment: Is there a way to pass params to btnS ? lets say cell B2 had a value that we wanted to pass to the btnS sub

Answer (score 4):

Suppose your function enters data in columns A and B and you want to a custom Userform to appear if the user selects a cell in column C. One way to do this is to use the `SelectionChange` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim clickRng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set clickRng = Range("C1:C" & lastRow) 'Dynamically set cells that can be clicked based on data in column A

    If Not Intersect(Target, clickRng) Is Nothing Then
        MyUserForm.Show 'Launch custom userform
    End If

End Sub
```

Note that the userform will appear when a user *selects* any cell in Column C and you might want to populate each cell in Column C with something like "select cell to launch form" to make it obvious that the user needs to perform an action (having a button naturally suggests that it should be clicked)