# Excel VBA create a button beside cell

Tags: vba, excel

for my question I would like to create a button beside the cell that is not NULL or "". The caption for the button must follow the value in the cell beside.

For example:

1. I typed 'EMPLOYEE' in `Range("D3")`
2. I want the macro to create a button named "EMPLOYEE" in the `Range("C3")`
3. However I want the macro to be dynamic so that every time I type in the value in the column 'D', the cell on the left side - `C3` will comes out a button.

Therefore, I've figured out that I needed to code for the `CommandButton` manually is that right?

Nevertheless, million thanks in advance for all.

Comment: First ... [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Second ... see the `Worksheet_Change` event and the `Macro Recorder` while doing what you want manually.

Comment: First, I did add the button into the ActiveSheet but got no clue on the 'Selection.OnAction = ' because the macro is a sub in my module.

Comment: What do you want the button to do?

Comment: `Selection.OnAction = ` would be if you wanted to click the button and perform a macro, which seems different than the question you asked. You don't need any button to create buttons...  unless I am confused.

Comment: Yes indeed sorry for the confusion. I wanted the worksheet_change() to create CommandButton for me under certain condition.

Comment: Why don't you post the code you've tried? Then we can help you edit it...  Also, `Selection.OnAction` follows this syntax `Selection.OnAction = "Workbookname!Macroname"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a button programmatically in VBA next to some sheet cell data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559094/how-to-add-a-button-programmatically-in-vba-next-to-some-sheet-cell-data)

Comment: @Remnant I want the button, when clicked, pop out a UserForm for data entry (I already done coding for the UserForm, just left the part mentioned in my question above)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I wanted to create CommandButton. Ain't 'Selection.OnAction' is for normal button?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes I've seen that thread but I wanted a CommandButton not a normal button (CommandButton looks better)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may **record a macro** by adding a command button to see how it's created and then incorporate the fancy parts. Note on properties of OLE Command button object, pay more attention to them.

e.g. `theButton.Name` yet for caption is set via `theButton.Object.Caption` etc.

**Here is a code snippet to get you going:-**

```
Option Explicit

Sub createButtons()
Dim theButton As OLEObject
Dim rngRange As Range
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set rngRange = Sheets(2).Range("B2")

    For i = 0 To 9
        If rngRange.Offset(i, 0).Value <> "" Then
        With rngRange.Offset(i, 1)
            Set theButton = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add _
                (ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
                Left:=.Left, _
                Top:=.Top, _
                Height:=.Height, _
                Width:=.Width)

                theButton.Name = "cmd" & rngRange.Offset(i, 0).Value
                theButton.Object.Caption = rngRange.Offset(i, 0).Value

                '-- you may edit other properties such as word wrap, font etc..
      End With
      End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Tan Siong Zhe please give this a try. Imagine how you would want to add a picture/image, rename it, and then position it in a cell :)

Comment: Thanks @bonCodigo Am trying now

Comment: Referring to your code, I set every 'Sheets(2)' to 'ActiveSheet'. There is one weird issue where it successfully creates a CommandButton but at the same time pop out "Run time error '438'" Object doesn't support this property or method. Any idea how the message exist?

Comment: @TanSiongZhe I was supposed to update this code. Error was due to `theButton.Object.Name` where as it should be `theButton.Name` :) Check now :) comment please.

Comment: Please check again your code. The coordinate of the buttons are off. Thank you. I'm working on it in the moment too.

Comment: The error was on this line 'With rngRange.Offset(i, i)' should change to 'With rngRange.Offset(i, 1)'

Comment: Excellent, that was typo happened while formatting here. I was wondering how there's an error when it output correct results. Please mark if all is good for you and happy to hear any further comments :-)

Comment: I've edited little in your code and it works perfectly for me. Thank you so much. I also marked yours as the answer. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @TanSiongZhe I would have given you the exact code, but I believe we do justice to the OP by encouraging him to try out with a proper direction we provide. Because it's more fun when you see finally your own code running up :) Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 2):

Try this out.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim row As Integer

    col = Target.Column
    row = Target.row

    If Not IsNull(Target.Value) And Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Buttons.Add Cells(row, col - 1).Left, Cells(row, col - 1).Top, Cells(row, col - 1).Width, Cells(row, col - 1).Height
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    End Sub
```

Open up the Developer Tab --> Visual Basic, double click "Sheet1", then paste this code in there. Test it by typing text in a cell on Sheet1 then moving away from that cell (e.g. by pressing Enter).

Comment: @TanSiongZhe I apologize, I'm just noticing that you specifically want a commandbutton, not a regular button. The above logic would remain the same, but you'll have to replace "Buttons.Add" with the appropriate code for [adding a commandbutton](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=8907)

Comment: Don't be :) Thanks for the link. Checking it out now.