# Error with creating command button during runtime

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module that creates command buttons during run-time. It will create the command buttons in a specified user-form. Program works fine, when I execute the module.

However when I use the user-form to call the module instead, I have a error stating

`Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set`

**Code**

```
 Sub AddButtonAndShow()

    Dim Butn As CommandButton
    Dim Line As Long
    Dim objForm As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    Set objForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Current_Stock")



For i = 1 To 3
    Set Butn = objForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
    With Butn
        .Name = "CommandButton" & i
        .Caption = i
        .Width = 100
        .Left = 300
        .Top = 10 * i * 2
    End With
Next

    For x = 1 To 3
        With objForm.CodeModule
            Line = .CountOfLines
            .InsertLines Line + 1, "Sub CommandButton" & x & "_Click()"
            .InsertLines Line + 2, "MsgBox ""Hello!"""
            .InsertLines Line + 3, "End Sub"
      End With
    '
     Next x

End Sub
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: Pld add more info about how you are  running the sub (from what control, from a UserForm `Current_Stock`? etc)

Comment: Can you please take a look at the answer provided and comment?

Answer (score 2):

### Editted post: based on VBProject Form Components

Earlier post is for Excel Sheet buttons. I noticed for Form buttons you may set the `caption` by directly referring to the `button` itself. I tried out your code. Doesn't seem to find any errors. The only addtional things I did was adding the reference Library (`MS VB Extensibility 5.3`), `Private` scope to code and combining code into one `with` statement.

As per this **[Mr.Excel article](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/42454-codemodule-insertline-only-working-if-vbe-open.html)**, you need add **`do Events`** to run the code when VB Editor is closed. Your error seems to be very much alike to what's mentioned in the article.

Revised Code:

```
Sub AddButtonAndShow()

    Dim Butn As CommandButton
    Dim Line As Long
    Dim objForm As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim code As String

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        DoEvents
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objForm = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
        objForm.Name = "thisform1"

        For i = 1 To 3
            Set Butn = objForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
            With Butn
                    .Name = "CommandButton" & i
                    .Caption = i
                    .Width = 100
                    .Left = 100
                    .Top = (i * 24) + 10

                    Line = objForm.CodeModule.CountOfLines + 1
                    code = "Private Sub " & Butn.Name & "_Click()" & vbCr
                    code = code & "MsgBox ""Hello!""" & vbCr
                    code = code & "End Sub"
                    objForm.CodeModule.InsertLines Line, code
              End With
        Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   VBA.UserForms.Add(objForm.Name).Show
End Sub
```

Excel Command Button code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Call AddButtonAndShow
End Sub
```

Output: Use an Excel Sheet button to open the newly created Form with buttons.

[image]

---

Initial post:

Please take a look at this post for reference: [Excel VBA create a button beside cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994014/excel-vba-create-a-button-beside-cell/13996162#13996162).

- Possible error due to *(`object doesn't support property or method`)*,  is within the `Caption` property. As it has to be set with **`theBttn.Object.Caption`**

Try this please:

```
With Butn
  .Name = "CommandButton" & i
  .Object.Caption = i
  .Width = 100
  .Left = 300
  .Top = 10 * i * 2
End With
```