# VBA - Handling Events from many Comboboxes, using class

Tags: excel, vba, class, events, combobox

I have the following issue.

My VBA program generates dinamically many comboboxes as I expected.

The problem comes when I try to handle their change-events. Searching on the web I saw that a class module is needed in these situations, so that's what I did.

Here is my class-module-code (class name: DB_ComboBox)

```
    Private WithEvents DB_ComboBoxEvents As MSForms.ComboBox
    Private DB_ComboBox_Line As Integer

    Private Sub DB_ComboBoxEvents_Change()
        MsgBox ("Line : " & DB_ComboBox_Line)
        'Here I will handle The comboboxes changes
    End Sub

    Public Property Let Box(value As MSForms.ComboBox)
        Set DB_ComboBoxEvents = value
    End Property
    Public Property Get Box() As MSForms.ComboBox
        Set Box = DB_ComboBoxEvents
    End Property


    Public Property Let Line(value As Integer)
        DB_ComboBox_Line = value
    End Property

    Public Property Get Line() As Integer
        Line = DB_ComboBox_Line
    End Property
```

Here the (simplified) code-portion in which I generate the comboboxes. As you can see, I'm trying to insert all the comboboxes into the array "customBox()"

```
Option Explicit

Private customBox() As New DB_ComboBox

Dim G_DBRigaInizioErrori As Integer
Dim G_IncBoxes As Integer

G_DBRigaInizioErrori = 5

For G_IncBoxes = G_DBRigaInizioErrori To 10
    CreateComboBox G_DBRigaInizioErrori, G_IncBoxes
Next


Sub CreateComboBox(DBRigaInizioErrori, IncCBoxes)

    Dim curCombo As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range


    ReDim Preserve customBox(IncCBoxes - DBRigaInizioErrori)


    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws

        Set rng = .Range("J" & IncCBoxes)


        Set curCombo = .Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, _
                                          Left:=rng.Left, _
                                          Top:=rng.Top, _
                                          Width:=rng.Width, _
                                          Height:=rng.Height)


        With curCombo

            .ControlFormat.AddItem "1", 1
            .name = "myCombo" & IncCBoxes

        End With

        Set customBox(IncCBoxes - DBRigaInizioErrori) = New DB_ComboBox
        customBox(IncCBoxes - DBRigaInizioErrori).Box = curCombo
        customBox(IncCBoxes - DBRigaInizioErrori).Line = IncCBoxes


    End With
End Sub
```

When I run this, I get the error "13" (not corresponding type) on the following line:

```
    customBox(IncCBoxes - DBRigaInizioErrori).Box = curCombo
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance

EDIT

Basing on the suggestions, I made the following changes:

1) Class Module

```
        Private WithEvents DB_ComboBoxEvents As Excel.OLEObject
    Private DB_ComboBox_Line As Integer

    Private Sub DB_ComboBoxEvents_Change()
        MsgBox ("Line : " & DB_ComboBox_Line)
        'Here I will handle The comboboxes changes
    End Sub

    Public Property Let Box(value As Excel.OLEObject)
        Set DB_ComboBoxEvents = value
    End Property
    Public Property Get Box() As Excel.OLEObject
        Set Box = DB_ComboBoxEvents
    End Property


    Public Property Let Line(value As Integer)
        DB_ComboBox_Line = value
    End Property

    Public Property Get Line() As Integer
        Line = DB_ComboBox_Line
    End Property
```

(I'm not sure about "Excel OLEObject", but the compiler doesn't complain , so I guess it is compatible with "WIthEvents")

"Main" Module:

```
    Option Explicit

    Private customBox() As New DB_ComboBox

    Dim G_DBRigaInizioErrori As Integer
    Dim G_IncBoxes As Integer

    G_DBRigaInizioErrori = 5

    For G_IncBoxes = G_DBRigaInizioErrori To 10
        CreateComboBox G_DBRigaInizioErrori, G_IncBoxes
    Next


    Sub CreateComboBox(DBRigaInizioErrori, IncCBoxes)

        Dim curCombo As Object
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim tot_items As Integer
        Dim incAddItem As Integer

        ReDim Preserve customBox(IncCBoxes - DBRigaInizioErrori)


        tot_items = 5

        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("J" & IncCBoxes)
        Set curCombo = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=rng.Left, Top:=rng.Top, Width:=rng.Width, Height:=rng.Height).Object


        For incAddItem = 1 To tot_items
            curCombo.AddItem "Hi"
        Next

        Set customBox(IncCBoxes - DBRigaInizioErrori) = New DB_ComboBox
        Set customBox(IncCBoxes - DBRigaInizioErrori).Box = curCombo
        customBox(IncCBoxes - DBRigaInizioErrori).Line = IncCBoxes


    End Sub
```

When I run this, I manage to create the first ComboBox (along with its items), but then I get an error "91" --> I verified that the execution  stops at the following line

```
Set customBox(IncCBoxes - DBRigaInizioErrori).Box = curCombo
```

Any further help would be really appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: `Private customBox() As New DB_ComboBox` is rather suspicious, and has all ingredients for a nice memory leak. Drop the `As New` there. Why not just use a `Collection`?

Comment: +You add a dropdown (form control) instead of an ActiveX control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit default member references strike again!

You're missing a `Set` keyword:

```
Set customBox(IncCBoxes - DBRigaInizioErrori).Box = curCombo
```

Without the `Set` keyword, what you're assigning is `.Box.Value` on LHS, which can't be right.

But there's another problem.

```
    Set curCombo = .Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, _
                                      Left:=rng.Left, _
                                      Top:=rng.Top, _
                                      Width:=rng.Width, _
                                      Height:=rng.Height)
```

That's not a `MSForm.ComboBox` control, that's an `Excel.ComboBox`. You need to add an ActiveX control, not a "form control". [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38615563/1188513) covers it.

Comment: Thank you, I modified my code but I still have some problems as you can see. Regarding using a Collection instead of an array, I will surely change this if it is necessary, but first I would like to be sure that the remaining code works propoerly (my experience with VBA is very limited, and my experience with VBA Collections is null so far). Thanks also to @EvR

Comment: For object properties, you need a `Property Set`; property `Let` is for value assignments, not objects. Also change the type back to `MSForm.ComboBox`, since you're setting it to `OleObject.Object`, which is a msforms combobox.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu, it works now. Thank you for the great explanation