# Excel VSTO Can't Add Button to Worksheet

Tags: c#, vb.net, vsto

I created a VB.NET Excel VSTO project Using VS 2019. I tried to add the controls like button, checkbox, textbox etc to the sheet directly like VBA ActiveX control (Not in the ribbon, ribbon works fine). But VS cant let me do that. It's Not showing any error, just not doing anything. Is it a bug, or I can't do that in VSTO? I have searched everywhere but can't find anything useful.

Comment: Try it may help , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559094/how-to-add-a-button-programmatically-in-vba-next-to-some-sheet-cell-data/4559676

Comment: Thanks, This is VBA, I am asking for VSTO. I dont know if its fits with VSTO or not. But worth a try